# destroy a particular li and it content after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
<ul>
    <li id="any_list">Content to be destroyed</li>
</ul>
```

and this link:
`<a href="#" onclick="return deleteList(document.getElementById('any_list'))">remove the list "#any_list"</a>`

How can I write the deleteList() function in order to the list #any_list and its content?

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire `ul`, or just the clicked on `li`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an element's parent using the `parentNode` property and you can remove a child element using the `removeChild` method. Therefore:

```
function deleteList(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rMPdn/1/

Try this, example above: -

```
$("#any_list").each(function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Comment: -1 for completely unnecessary `.each` and for failing to show how to bind the handler.

Comment: @Alnitak I do apologise that my reading of the question and interpreting it to mean that the poster wanted to delete any list as a class has offended you so much, especially seeing as how after I have posted you have posted such a similar answer. However I still think it bares merit that I went to the effort to include an example and future viewers of this post may need what I have posted. I feel this was a comment or a flag at the very most quite frankly.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to pollute the markup. Give the link an id first.

```
<a href="#" id="delete_any_list">remove the list "#any_list"</a>
```

Then simply

```
$('#delete_any_list').click(function(e){
  $('#any_list').remove(); 
     e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add an `id` to your anchor and remove any inline Javascript:

```
<a href="#" id="delete_any_list">remove the list "#any_list"</a>
```

[it's considered poor practice these days to ever actually put any JS code directly into the markup].

Then, in your jQuery `document.ready` function add this:

```
$('#delete_any_list').click(function(ev) {
    $('#any_list').remove();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/MbZpV/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#delete_any_list").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#any_list").remove();
    });
});

<a href="#" id="delete_any_list">Delete any list</a>
```